# jQuery validator not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have included jQuery validate for my site for uploading advertisement file..
I don't know why but this is not working.

HTML file is as following:

```
<form  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_data.jsp"  id="formToPushAd" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td width="100px">Ad Image:</td>
            <td><input type="file" name="file"/></td>
        </tr>  
        <tr>
            <td width="100px">Ad URL:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="adUrl"/></td>
        </tr>  
        <tr>
            <td>Starting Date:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="datepicker1" name="datepicker1" /></td>
        </tr>       
        <tr>
            <td>Ending Date:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="datepicker2" name="datepicker2" onchange="dateSelected()"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit"/></td>
```

jQuery validate script is added before this script

And js file is:

```
$().ready(function(){
    $("#formToPushAd").validate({
        rules:{
            file:{
                required:true
            },
            adUrl:{
                required:true,
                url:true
            },
            datepicker1:{
                required:true,
                date:true
            },
            datepicker2:{
                required:true,
                date:true,
            }
        },
        messages:{      
            file:{
                required:"Please Select a frequency"
            },
            adUrl:{
                required:"Please enter ad url"
            },
            datepicker1:{
                required:"Please Enter a date",
                date:"Please Enter a valid date"    
            },
            datepicker2:{
                required:"Please Enter a date",
                date:"Please Enter a valid date"
            }
        }

    })
});
```

What is the problem?

Comment: So what is the issue??? Error in console? Etc...

Comment: i think replace this tag... datepicker2:{
            required:true,
            date:true
        }

Comment: .validate function not found

Comment: *"`.validate()` function not found"* means that you **failed to properly include the plugin**.  Otherwise, your code would be working:  http://jsfiddle.net/4toLj0kw/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you don't included `jQuery` and `validate` libraries because it **works fine** when you add them in your header

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$().ready(function(){
$("#formToPushAd").validate({
    rules:{
        file:{
            required:true
        },
        adUrl:{
            required:true,
            url:true
        },
        datepicker1:{
            required:true,
            date:true
        },
        datepicker2:{
            required:true,
            date:true,
        }
    },
    messages:{      
        file:{
            required:"Please Select a frequency"
        },
        adUrl:{
            required:"Please enter ad url"
        },
        datepicker1:{
            required:"Please Enter a date",
            date:"Please Enter a valid date"    
        },
        datepicker2:{
            required:"Please Enter a date",
            date:"Please Enter a valid date"
        }
    }

})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_data.jsp" id="formToPushAd" method="post">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td width="100px">Ad Image:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="file" name="file" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="100px">Ad URL:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="adUrl" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Starting Date:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="datepicker1" name="datepicker1" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ending Date:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="datepicker2" name="datepicker2" onchange="dateSelected()" />
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" />
      </td>
    </tr>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change   $().ready(function() to $(document).ready(function() and ensure the plugin files and jquery.min files have been included on the page.

Comment: Both syntaxes work although that's true binding it to document is preferred method  https://api.jquery.com/ready/#entry-longdesc

Answer (score -1):

you should use `onsubmit` on form , to validate the data .you should also call `e.preventDefault()` which will prevent the form from firing more than once

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/m27Ljpb9/1/

```
<form  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#"  id="formToPushAd" method="post" onsubmit="validateData(event)">
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td width="100px">Ad Image:</td>
        <td><input type="file" name="file"/></td>
   </tr>  
   <tr>
        <td width="100px">Ad URL:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="adUrl"/></td>
   </tr>  
   <tr>
        <td>Starting Date:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="datepicker1" name="datepicker1"/></td>
   </tr>       
   <tr>
        <td>Ending Date:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="datepicker2" name="datepicker2" onchange="dateSelected()"/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
        <td><input type="submit"/></td>
   </tr>
</form>
<script>
function validateData(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     rules:{
        file:{
            required:true
        },
        adUrl:{
            required:true,
            url:true
        },
        datepicker1:{
            required:true,
            date:true
        },
        datepicker2:{
            required:true,
            date:true,
        }
    },
    messages:{      
        file:{
            required:"Please Select a frequency"
        },
        adUrl:{
            required:"Please enter ad url"
        },
        datepicker1:{
            required:"Please Enter a date",
            date:"Please Enter a valid date"    
        },
        datepicker2:{
            required:"Please Enter a date",
            date:"Please Enter a valid date"
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: i have provided right method to them , not sure what needs to be validated , so that is flexible , what i spoke here is onsubmit we can call a function , provide a e.preventDefualt(), which will prevent it from executing more than once and then validate what ever they wanted to

Comment: The OP is asking specifically about how to use [the jQuery Validate plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org).   **[Your answer is completely wrong and totally broken](http://jsfiddle.net/m27Ljpb9/1/)**.  You've simply stuck the object literal containing the rules & options intended for the `.validate()` method into a JavaScript function.  You've also used inline JavaScript which is unnecessary when using jQuery.